# How to combine two api response data into single list of data

Tags: flutter, list, dart, builder

I am having two set of apis. Which gives me a list of array of data.

For ex:

First api returns "postData".
Second api return "promotionData".

Now i have to list the postdata in a page. I used Listview.builder to show all the postData api response data.

Now i have promotionData which return another set of json list of data.

The actual output i need is i want to display the five data of postData and then in between i have to show promotionData details and then postData details.

This is similar to FB and Twritter. Where we can see 5 posts and one promoAdd data.

How can i do this. Please help fnz.....

Answer (score 0):

Just build a combined list.
Something like:

```
// replace String to actual object that you are using
List<String> combinedList = [];
int promotionIndex = 0;
for (var postIndex=0 ; postIndex < postData.length ; postIndex++) {
    if (postIndex > 0 && postIndex % 5 == 0) {
         combinedList.add(promotionData[promotionIndex]);
         promotionIndex++;
    }
    combinedList.add(postData[postIndex]);
}
```

Comment: combinedList is not type of String. I am calling the postData and promotionData with model data separately. So i cannot able to add to combined list? Pls help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `combinedList`, you could change your `ListView.builder` instead:

```
// variable in your widget
int _promotionIndex = 0;
...
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: postData.lenght + promotionData.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if((index + 1) % 5 == 0) { //important line
     // return your PromotionWidget here
     // access it with promotionData[promotionIndex]
     promotionIndex++;
    }
    // return your PostWidget here
  },
)
```

`(index + 1) % 5 == 0` provides the functionality you need, as it check whether the index is divisible by 5.